# Ubuntu VMWare boot ends up at initramfs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I have a problem with Ubuntu systems I’m running on VMware.  Often with Ubuntu images that are running fine, I’ll pause them, save them and then exit VMWare and then when I come back to use the VM I get the following problem when I boot up:
see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhMcT.png

I can’t get past the initramfs prompt with “exit”
see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIqCC.png

I’ve tried running “fsck” but I can’t get see the device here I expect  – it informs that /dev/sda (or /dev/sdb)  doesn’t exist – so that remediation isn’t working.

I’m assuming now this is a problem specific to VMWare Workstation Pro 16.2.3 build-19376536 (I have about 5 - 6 VMware images and they have all suffered the same fate). Some of my snapshots work, but I can’t reboot them and when I try to `ls /mnt/data` I’m getting the message `-ls: reading directory ‘.’: Host is down`

This is making me lose my mind because I’ve rebuilt these images recently. Why are these images failing? Is there anything I can do to recover them? Am I doing something obviously wrong in how I'm creating these images? (I create a VM and install an Ubuntu image from a .iso image from the ubuntu site).

Comment: Why are these images failing? ..... If I read correctly, you said you are pausing the machine (so suspend) to make a copy. You should shut the machine down completely to save a copy. I do it this way to ensure the main system and copy are safe. I am not sure how you will recover the main system at this point.

Comment: At this stage, I do not know of any sequence of sudo commands that will fix this. Make a new good system, and then be sure to shut down before saving an image. If you shut down, the main VM will not be damaged.

Comment: Thank you John, It seems then I inadvertently shot myself in the foot on this operation - I thought  suspending was adequate to save a copy.